# Cómo llamar a una función asíncrona dentro de una Promesa .then ()

Tags: javascript, nodejs, async-await

Estoy haciendo una api rest para enviar correos electrónicos y en el bloque de archivos adjuntos (attachments) tuve un problema, estoy trabajando con SQL server.
¿Cómo puedo resolver esta promesa? Cuando lo ejecuto, me devuelve indefinido.
Creo que finaliza el proceso antes de devolver el resultado de la promesa.
Quizás me esté perdiendo algo.

```
exports.getExecute = (req, res, next) => {
        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
         var products = Product.findAll({
            where: {
                status: null
            },
            order: [
                'priority'
            ]
        })
          resolve(products)
        })
        .then( (products) => {
            for (let mail of products) {
                mail.attachments = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    var att_array = [Attachment.findAll({
                        where: {
                            id: mail.attachments_id
                        },
                        attributes: ['path', 'filename']
                    })]
                     resolve(att_array)
                     console.log(mail.attachments);
                   });
            }
            return products
        })
        )
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Please translate your question, this is a spanish site.

Comment: Product.findAll devuelve una promesa o es un método síncrono? No entiendo para qué usas la primera promesa

Comment: Lo que hace es buscar todos los archivos adjuntos en la base de datos en los que el estado sea nulo, en base a eso hago el .then para asociar el attachment_id al archivo que se encuentra en la base de datos. no se si me explico bien @PabloLozano

Comment: Realmente no has respondido a la pregunta: si es un método síncrono (devuelve los datos directamente) no necesitas la primera promesa para nada

Comment: O dicho de otro modo: ¿qué librería estás usando para acceder a tu base de datos?

Comment: estoy utilizando sequelize @PabloLozano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La librería Sequelize funciona con promesas, por tanto podrías hacer algo como:

```
exports.getExecute = (req, res, next) => {
    
    Product.findAll({
        where: {
            status: null
        },
        order: [
            'priority'
        ]
    }).then( (products) => {
        
      //lo que quieras hacer con los productos
      //usar res para responder algo
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @PabloLozano